# Is it possible to rank on a keyword, even if Google treats the keyword like a location search?

Tags: seo, google-search, keywords, search-results, geolocation

Is it possible to rank on Google with keywords that will only locally appear in the search results?

Like if I want to make a site about gyms. If someone searches for this keyword he will only find sites about local gyms.

Is it possible to rank on Google on a keyword, even if Google treats the keyword like a location search?

Comment: I see Wikipedia at #10 in the search results for "gyms".  If I go to page 2, I see several global sites ranking such as the Washington Post and a site about Pokemon.

Comment: Ok, so is it possible to rank on the first rank on those keywords ? Because for the keyword ,,schwimmbad" which stands for swimming pool in english there is wikipedia on the 6th place and above wiki is a news container 5 other websites of local swimming pools and on the top is the google map for local businesses.

Comment: I realized that the local businesses appear, when google is allowed to use your location. Its still possible to get people on your site where doesn't have this option enabled.